# How to stop these Vim errors?

Tags: vim

It seems like almost every time I open a file in Vim anymore, I'll get an error like this:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/me/.vim/view/=+something=+something=+something...
E518: Unknown option: nomacmeta
```

The option is usually something different depending on the file.  I've done `:help view` but the results weren't very helpful. Is there some way I can disable this view feature so I can stop getting these errors?  I don't have time to run down every one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:help 'macmeta'` is an option specific to MacVim. You are having this error because you are sourcing a view script that contains the command `set nomacmeta` in a Vim that is not MacVim and thus doesn't support that option.

Either…

- you are on a Mac but you are using the built-in Vim at `/usr/bin/vim`, which is not MacVim,
- or you are on a Mac but you are using a manually built Vim, which is very likely to not be MacVim,
- or you are on some other system where Vim is pretty much guaranteed to not be MacVim.

To prevent those errors, remove any non-cross-platform option from your view scripts and consider reading `:help :mkview` carefully, specially the part about `:help 'viewoptions'`.

Also, `&macmeta` is disabled by default so disabling it doesn't make much sense to begin with.